# Cord system and units?

Tags: opengl

How do I change default cord system and units in OpenGL?

Right now it's using the default, meaning it goes from -1.0 (left) to 1.0 (right) with 0 being the origin (same with Y, -1.0 being top, 1.0 being bottom).

Optimally I would 1) want to change units to roughly same number of pixels.  For example, on an 800x600 display have it go from -400 to 400 (on x) and -300 to 300  (on y).  Seems like it would be easier to work with than -1.0 to 1.0

2) Bonus points: how do I change the x/y?  One game engine had I seen had it go from 0 to maxWidth and 0 to maxHeight.

That is, 0,0 was top left and 800,600 was bottom right.  (0, 600 would be left bottom and 800,0 would be top right)

I think these both have to do with the viewpoint command, but don't know if I fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answering your last point: There is no "viewpo *i* nt" commant. There is *glViewport* which defines the mapping from so called clip space [-1,1]×[-1,1]×[-1,1] into window/screen space — **important:** *glViewport* doesn't set some clipping, so if your viewport only covers some smaller, middle part of your window, things that exceed the viewport in rendering may/will cause artifacts outside the viewport. Scissor testing (enabled and set with *glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)* and *glScissor*) does this kind of clipping, which also works within the viewport (nice for implementing selection rubber bands!).

Now to cover your first question: OpenGL's coordinate system is whatever you want it to be; in OpenGL-3.1 and OpenGL-4 there's no default coordinate system at all! In OpenGL-2 and below there are a number of so called *transformation matrices*, most importantly *modelview* and *projection*.

You can think *projection* to be some kind of a camera's lens (although it works entirely differently). What is does is, it transforms the *world* (or modelview) space into the aforementioned *clip space*. It is this projection matrix, that allows you map any *affine* coordinate system into clip space. OpenGL before version 3 provides you helper functions *glFrustum* and *glOrtho* for the most oftenly used projections: Perspective and Ortho.

Let's construct some projection ourself (it's an ortho, but I'd like to show how things work on the math side). Say you'd like to map x in [0; 200], y in [0; 100] to [-1; 1] (left to right), [-1,1] (top to bottom), and leave z as it is. Then

```
x_clip = -1 + x*(1-(-1))*(200-0) = -1 + x*2/200
y_clip =  1 + y*(-1  1 )*(100-0) =   1 + x*(-2)/100
z_clip = z
```

This translates into the following matrix:

```
2/200      0     0    -1
    0 -2/100     0     1
    0      0     1     0
    0      0     0     1
```

You could now put this into the projection matrix using *glLoadMatrix*.

The *modelview* matrix is used for moving stuff around in the world space. It's also used to define the viewpoint: OpenGL has no camera. Instead we just move the whole world in an opposite way to how we'd moved a camera within the world to the desired viewpoint (this time …point, not …port!)

Answer (score 1):

[`glOrtho()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

unsigned int win_w = 0;
unsigned int win_h = 0;

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, win_w, win_h, 0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(50,50,50);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(0,1);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    win_w = w;
    win_h = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutCreateWindow("Ortho);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```